# How to create a server which creates a new thread for each client?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I need to create a server which creates a new thread for each client trying to connect to the server. The new thread created for each client manages the client and the server process listens for new connections from the port.

I need to code in Unix C. This is a sub-task of the task I need to finish as soon as possible. I am new to this field and hence do not know much about creating servers.

Comment: Post some code so we've got something to work with.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing, Tutorial or Consulting Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496)

Comment: you need to create a service that does this?   or you are loading up a new server and need to configure it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you're looking for is something like this :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* handle_connection(void *arg)
{
    int client_sock = *(int*)arg;
    /* handle the connection using the socket... */
}

int main(void)
{
    /* do the necessary setup, i.e. bind() and listen()... */
    int client_sock;
    pthread_t client_threadid;
    while((client_sock = accept(server_sock, addr, addrlen)) != -1)
    {
        pthread_create(&client_threadid,NULL,handle_connection,&client_sock);
    }
}
```

This is a pretty basic skeleton for a server application which creates a different thread for every incoming client connection. If you don't know what `bind`, `listen`, or `accept` is, then consult the second section of your local manual.

Comment: This code contains the classic race condition. You cannot pass the address of `client_sock` to the new thread unless you're going to synchronize access to it. I would use `(void *)client_sock`, but if you find that really icky you can waste time and memory calling `malloc` for it or add a semaphore or other synchronization object (also wasting lots of time).

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll just stick to useless assembly-related questions the next time around.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit harsh. When a newbie is asking a threads question, though, giving them an answer that contains one of the classic thread-beginner mistakes is a bit troublesome at best. Note that someone who used this answer would probably never catch the race condition since `accept` is sufficiently slow that it would be extremely rare for the new thread not to have started by the time the main thread overwrites the variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all take a look at https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ . It's tutorial about thread library for C. Enjoy!