# Multithreaded server client code

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads, client-server

I am writing code for multithreaded server. I have come across this question : 
[How to create a server which creates a new thread for each client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074375/how-to-create-a-server-which-creates-a-new-thread-for-each-client)

I am using the accepted answer's skeleton with the suggested change of the first comment. My only problem is I don't understand what the comment means. Why do I have to synchronize access to the client_sock ? I have read the description in the lower comment, but since the pthread line is processed only after accept () is done, how does it create a race condition? Also why does (void *) cast help?

Also, please explain

> add a semaphore or other synchronization object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the casting, the last argument to `pthread_create` is a *pointer*, and will be the argument to the thread function. If you want to pass something that isn't a pointer then you need to cast it to a pointer, and have the corresponding cast in the thread function to get the original type back.

The reason the skeleton is flawed and you need to pass the actual value of the socket (casted to a pointer) is because otherwise *all* the threads will use the exact same socket, and the earlier threads will "magically" start reading from and writing to the last accepted socket. At least without synchronization, which is where the semaphore comes in.

If you protect the accepted socket with a semaphore (or other synchronization primitive) then you can still pass a pointer, and release the semaphore in the thread once it has copied the actual socket value.

So you need to do something like (pseudo-code)

```
while (not_exit_server_program)
{
    wait_for_new_connection_to_arrive();
    wait_for_semaphore(socket_semaphore);
    new_socket = accept(...);
    pthread_create(..., &new_socket);
}
```

Then in the thread function

```
void *client_thread_function(void *pointer_to_socket)
{
    int socket = *(int *) pointer_to_socket;
    release_semaphore(socket_semaphore);

    ... rest of function
}
```